# How to know the UITableview row number and section name using UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableviewcell with UISwitch of each cell. When I change the value of the switch in a cell, how can I show the alert View or popup and display the Row No and Section No.i want to function apply in Cell we show simple alert view.

This is my code

```
@interface ADIViewController ()

@end

@implementation ADIViewController
{
   // NSArray* views;
    NSArray* countswitch;
    UITableView* tableview;
}

- (id)initWithStyle :(UITableViewStyle)style
{

    self = [super initWithStyle :style];
    if (self)
{
        // Custom initialization
}
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // add to canvas
    [self.view addSubview :tableview];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView :(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return SECTION_TOTAL_COUNT;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection :(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == SECTION_ID_PROFILE)
{
    return 7;
}

    if(section == SECTION_ID_SETTINGS)
{
    return 5;
}

    return 3;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection :(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == SECTION_ID_PROFILE)
        return @"Account Profile";

    if(section == SECTION_ID_SETTINGS)
        return @"Account Settings";

    return @"Account VaxVoip";

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"ADiCell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but
    ADICell* ADiCell = (ADICell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier :cellIdentifier];

    if (ADiCell == 0)

{
    ADiCell = [[ADICell alloc] initWithStyle :UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier :cellIdentifier];
}

    // Just want to test, so I hardcode the data

    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed :@"ADiCell" owner :self options :NULL];


    ADiCell = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"hy");

    for (UIView* View in views)
{
   ADiCell = (ADICell*) View;
   ADiCell.countlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %d", [indexPath row]];


}

    return ADiCell;
}
```

and this is a Cell Code

```
@implementation ADICell

@synthesize countlabel = _countlabel;
@synthesize controlleswitch = _controlleswitch;


- (IBAction)ADIcontrollerswitch :(id)sender
{
    if(self.controlleswitch.isOn == FALSE)
{
    UIAlertView* ret = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle :@"Vaxsoft" message :@"Hello" delegate :nil cancelButtonTitle :@"Done" otherButtonTitles :nil];

    [ret show];
}
}

- (void)setSelected :(BOOL)selected animated :(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated :animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: You could set a tag to each cells, or an IndexPath.

Comment: i have using a custom cell and i don't know how tag every cell

Comment: @iOSHero u don't need to tag it u can follow my answer to get the find the actual cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can add switch in each cell in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`. you can set selector for valueChangeEvent of switch. Consider your selector name is `switchValueChanged:` and you can get superview of switch that will be your cell, after having cell get `indexPath` for that cell.

```
- (void)switchValueChanged:(id)sender{
  UISwitch switch = (UISwitch*)sender;
  CGPoint center= switch.center; 
  CGPoint cellPoint= [sender.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:cellPoint];

  // Now you can use indexPath.row and IndexPath.section wh
}
```

Comment: [switch superView]; will not work in ios7. all child of cell will present inside a new Scrollview in ios7.

Answer (score 0):

you can add  one more property to your `ADICell`  class When you add the row in the UITableDelegateMethod `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 , You can put your `rowNumber =indexpath.row` .

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"ADiCell";

    // Similar to UITableViewCell, but
    ADICell* ADiCell = (ADICell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier :cellIdentifier];

    if (ADiCell == 0)

{
    ADiCell = [[ADICell alloc] initWithStyle :UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier :cellIdentifier];
    ADiCell.rowNumber = indexPath.row;  // assign row number

}

    // Just want to test, so I hardcode the data

    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed :@"ADiCell" owner :self options :NULL];


    ADiCell = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"hy");

    for (UIView* View in views)
{
   ADiCell = (ADICell*) View;
   ADiCell.countlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %d", [indexPath row]];

}

    return ADiCell;
}
```

now yopu have the row number of every cell in property `rownumber` . Now you can use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can either subclass the UISwitch and add custom data to it or better use objc_setAssociatedObject() to connect the switch to an indexPath as described for example in this example: http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/associated-objects/

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint pointInTable = [switch convertPoint:switch.bounds.origin toView:_tableView];    

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
```

with the help of above code u can calculate the actual **index path of the cell.**

So u can use this code in switch action to find the actual cell the update the cell.

Comment: u have to use this code where u actually receive the switch toggle action.